Fail2ban: working and updated apache-badbots.conf for Debian12 needed
I've noticed a significant increase in crawler traffic on my Debian 12 server's access_log, including bots like Barkrowler, Bytespider, meta-externalagent, and others. A typical entry looks like this:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [04/Nov/2024:02:21:49 -0500] "GET /something.php?somepage HTTP/1.1" 200 29687 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Barkrowler/0.9; +https://babbar.tech/crawler)"

I've set up Fail2ban (version 1.0.2) with the apache-badbots filter, but it appears outdated and doesn't seem to catch anything at all.
Could anyone share a working apache-badbots.conf file?
Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Simplified the request as suggested.
